# Icon above TextViewLayout underline

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

I would to add icon above TextViewLayout underline like in this photo:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: I have just EditText, underline is drawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just try this:-**

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/imageWillChange"
```

OR

Try this :-

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Nothing happens